# Tapestry 5.3.6 select component disappears while dragging the scroll bar in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, select, scrollbar, tapestry

I've got text field with autocomplete mixin showing the list of movies when at least three letters are typed in. There is a lot of movies, so the select shows the scroll bar as well. In Chrome or FF, I am able to scroll down with mouse wheel or grab the scroll bar and drag it down or up. However, in IE 10, if I drag the scroll bar, the whole select will disappear. Has anybody come across this issue?

Note: Select has been modified in order to change the styling, position and also to be able to submit chosen value in ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess my question is a duplicate of the following one:
[Scriptaculous Autocomplete list closes on scroll bar click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481042/scriptaculous-autocomplete-list-closes-on-scroll-bar-click)
Consider this question irrelevant then.